# Unity Cloud Build iOS error Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Im trying to build mobile game on iOS using Unity Cloud Building. Im getting errors:

```
13817: ▸ ❌;  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7
13818: ▸ > Symbol: _requestReview
13819: ▸ > Referenced from: _LevelManager_Start_m2992410788 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
13820: ▸ ❌;  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
13821: ▸ ❌;  clang: error:
13822: ▸ Compiling UnityAppController+UnityInterface.mm
13823: ▸ Compiling UnityAppController+Rendering.mm
13824: ▸ Compiling UnityAdsUnityWrapper.mm
13825: ▸ Compiling StoreReview.m
13826: ▸ Compiling SplashScreen.mm
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Go to `build settings > Valid architectures > Select standard` and try again.

Comment: @SharadChauhan where can i find this? Remember, im using Unity CloudBuilding

Comment: Are you trying to merge ios and unity or its just unity ?

Comment: Its just unity project with some plugins. I didnt add any extra ios things. Im working on windows, and want to build iOS wersion by cloudBuilding.

Comment: What I said was for iOS + Unity ( my bad ), but this setting is in Unity too, you need to check built settings before Unity.

Comment: All i can do in Unitys build settings now is change Compression Method., which didnt help